# how to pass all student_id in checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having check box for selecting students in a particular class.But the unselected student id's are not passing via check box.Please help me. And also I have included coding below.

In View

```
<%= label_tag :students %>
  <button type="button" id="check_all">
    Check / Uncheck All
</button>

<table id = "mark"> 
    <tr>
        <td>
<table >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Students List</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @student.each do |i| %>  
            <tr>
                <td><%= check_box_tag :student, i.id %><%= i.first_name.capitalize %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
    </tbody>
    </table>        
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>

</tr>
</td>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Js file

```
$('#check_all').on("click", function(){ $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(); });
```

Comment: You want to send unselected student's ids to controller when you submit form? Or want to know how select/unselect students in one class, but not in all school? Or your JS code works wrong? (it's true)

Comment: I want to send unselected students id's to controller. when I submit a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that in two ways at least.

one) deducting the submitted students from the students collection ids:

```
unselected_ids = @student.collect(&:id) - params[:student].collect(&:to_i)
```

two)  setting another hidden field from client site using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden input with the same `name` before checkbox and zero value.

```
<input type='hidden' value='0' name='student'>
<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='student'>
```

When form submitted and checkbox is checked previous `0` value overwrites by `1`. If checkbox not checked then `0` value sends to the controller.
Bur its works only if you have one value, but you have a lot of ids. And you must use `student[]` name in checkboxes, if you use `student` name then only last checked value sends in controller by in `params[:student]`

In this case use can use this construction in your code:

```
<% @student.each do |s| %>  
    <tr><td>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "student_all[]", s.id %>
        <%= check_box_tag "student[]", s.id %><%= s.first_name.capitalize %>
    </td></tr>
<% end %>
```

And in controller get unchecked students like:

```
student_unchecked = params[:student_all] - params[:student]
```